# Delphi service on 64 bit machine using SVCOM raises error on stopping service

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have rebuilt my Delphi service that uses SvCom on a 64 bit machine. I have debugged the service and it all seems to work fine. However, when I install the service it works fine but on stopping, the service does stop but I get an error : "Error 1061 : service cannot accept control messages at this time".

Any ideas?

JD

Comment: What Delphi version? I'm using it under D2009 and Vista x64 and it's working fine (with just small fixes to proper support for Description and error actions - PAnsiChar!=PChar in D2009+). As I remember setting Description/error-actions can overwrite app memory (without fixes)
Try build simple service and start/stop it (best with FullDebugMode - FastMM4)

Comment: Using Codegear Rad Studio (2007). I am wondering if I need to patch delphi as I did have issues the other day applying it.

Comment: 1. Try build simple SvCom service and start/stop it. Did it worked?
2. If simple service works fine, then rebuild you app with FullDebugMode - FastMM4
3. Maybe you've blocked some eventes, and your service is in state other than Running (before service stop run cmd.exe and type: sc query "YourServiceName")?

Comment: Simple service had problems as well closing down. Clearly an SVCOM problem. Thanks for all the help and I will post once I resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically down to a fault in SvCom.  It constructs a custom bit of asm to execute the services main which won't work for 64bit.

You can either wait for a patch from svCom, create a replacement TNTService component or simply recut your service from TService.

Answer (score 1):

Please try SvCom 7.3, there are some essential bugfixes. It was successfully tested in 64x environment. Please let us know if the problem persists in 7.3 version.